# Primefaces CRUD Generator one-to-many insert parent id JPA

Tags: jpa, one-to-many, cascade

From the primefaces CRUD generator plugin for NetBeans, I get the following code for the **parent** table:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id_comments")
private Long idComments;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "docDownloadComment")
private Collection<PmMain> pmMainCollection;
```

And the **child** is:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "doc_download_comment", referencedColumnName = "id_comments")
@ManyToOne
private Comments docDownloadComment;
```

How can I insert the generated `id_comments` into the `doc_donwload_comment` whenever I create a record in the `comments` table?

Comment: The PrimeFaces 'crud' generator is from Netbeans or IntelliJ but not from PrimeFaces. There is nothing in the code above that is PF related. Try in a unit-test first...

Comment: you should add a cascade = CascadeType.ALL to your @OneToMany annotation, and mappedBy = "docDownloadComment" indicates the attribute related from the other side, so when you add an object to the collection the id_comments is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to Rjiuk and Billy Hope.

I'd like to share my solution for those of you that use **Primefaces CRUD Generator**.

**Parent**:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id_comments")
private Long idComments;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "docDownloadComment")
private List<PmMain> pmMainCollection = new ArrayList<>();

[... Getters and Setters ...]

public void setDocDownloadComment(PmMain pmMain){
    pmMain.setDocDownloadComment(this);
    pmMainCollection.add(pmMain);
}
```

**Child** stays the same.

**ParentController** add this:

```
@Inject
CommentsFacade commentsFacadeEJB;
@Inject
PmMainFacade pmMainFacadeEJB;
public void saveDocDownloadComment(long idPmMain, String commentText){

    PmMain pmMain = pmMainFacadeEJB.find(idPmMain);
    Comments comments = new Comments();

    pmMain.setDocDownloadComment(comments);
    comments.setDocDownloadComment(pmMain);

    comments.setCommentText(commentText);
    commentsFacadeEJB.edit(comments);

}
```

And call this method like from primefaces like:

```
<h:form id="ddCommentCreateForm">
    <h:panelGroup id="ddDisplay">

        <p:outputPanel id="ddCommentsPanel">

            <p:row>
                <p:column>
                    <p:inputTextarea id="commentText" value="#{commentsController.selected.commentText}" cols="100" rows="20" style="margin-bottom:10px"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:row>

        </p:outputPanel>

        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{commentsController.saveDocDownloadComment(pmMainController.selected.idPmMain, commentsController.selected.commentText)}" value="#{myBundle.Save}" update="ddDisplay,:PmMainListForm:datalist,:growl" oncomplete="handleSubmit(xhr,status,args,PF('ddDialog'));">
            <p:confirm header="#{myBundle.ConfirmationHeader}" message="#{myBundle.ConfirmEditMessage}" icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:commandButton value="#{myBundle.Cancel}" oncomplete="PF('ddDialog').hide()" update="nsDisplay" process="@this" immediate="true" resetValues="true"/>


    </h:panelGroup>

</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you persist **Comment** and you want to persist **PmMain** with it

### On your own

You would have to persist your **Comment** object.

Then persist every object of **PmMain** class where you set docDownloadComment to the Comment you have perisited ealier.

Like that :

`entityManager.persist(comment)`

```
//then
comment = entityManager.merge(comment);

...
pmMain.setDocDownloadComment(comment);
entityManager.persist(pmMain);
//for all pmMains
```

### CascadeType.PERSIST

You might also set CascadeType on this relation to automaticlly save all PmMains along your new Comment. For more information check [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gy-qZ1GksNs).